Is it possible for a phone to be infected without any attack vector?
I have a Samsung Galaxy S10+ Exynos on Android 12. For months, my phone was slow, super hot, and crashing a lot whenever I connected to WiFi.
I formatted the phone several times. After that, I decided to install Bitdefender on my phone (paid). After formatting the phone and installing Bitdefender, my phone stopped crashing, heating up, and slowing down.
The question I wanted to ask is if a phone can be infected without any attack vector, just by connecting to WiFi (which I think was the reason for the infection). I didn't install anything from outside the Play Store and this always happened to my phone.

Depending on the age of your phone Wifi Bluetooth and similar technologies itself can be an attack vector if the drivers are vulnerable.

my phone is a Galaxy s10+ exynos android 12

Galaxy s10+ does not receive updates since April 2023, thus it would be possible that it can be attacked on network level without user interaction.

@Robert Are there any CVEs that document such a possibility for such a new device and Android version?

Hi, just in case you might also be interested in our sister site [security.se].

@EndAntisemiticHate Google publishes every moths about 10-40 CVEs for Android. That does not include the Samsung specific CVEs (because of special drivers, chips, modifications, ...). For the AOSP CVEs see  https://source.android.com/docs/security/bulletin

So to stay protected I should use a custom rom preferably aosp? Ex lineageos?

Would this prevent vulnerability in Samsung components since AOSP roms are not based on OneUI?
